# Need to solve for $x$ in equation with XOR and Bit Rotation (Circular Shift)

Tags: computational-mathematics

I'm not the best with math and I've been needing to solve this equation which includes the XOR operator for 32 bit integers and some bit rotation (circular shifting).

$y$ = ($x$ ⊕ 32757935 * $i$ ⊕ ROR($x$, 3) ⊕ ROL($x$, 7))

Where

- ⊕ is the XOR operator for 32 bit integers.
- ROR and ROL are functions for circular shifting ROR(IGHT), ROL(EFT)
- $*$ stands for multiplication for 32 bit integers.

$i$ and $y$ will be known but $x$ will not be known
$i$ is unique for every value of $y$ and $x$

Comment: What is the * operation ? ... & $i,y$ & $x$ each consist of $32$ bits ... will there be some question as to weather $x$ exists, to satisfy this equation ?

Comment: * would stand for regular multiplication and yes they would all consist of **32** bits, and I would presume $x$ must exist.

Comment: It would seems I have figured it out, feel free to answer this question if you want!

Comment: It is perfectly acceptable for you to answer your own question ... indeed I would be intrigued to see what the solution looks like ... Please surprise me.